# Simple multiplication and division calculator on Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, calculator

Here is the exercise:

> single parameter is operator with arguments of * or / operator
>
> default operator is "*" (multiply)
>
> return the result of multiplication or division
>
> if operator other than "*" or "/" then return "Invalid Operator"

There's plenty that's confusing me about the instructions here, and I'm aware that I haven't solved it but here's the closest I have come to solving this:

```
def multiply(operator):

op = (x)

return op

ops = input ("what would you like the operator to be? ")

x = input()

y = input()

if ops == "*":

return int (x) * int (y)

elif ops == "/":

return int (x) / int (y)

else:

return "invalid operator"

print (multiply())
```

I can't keep `return" outside of the function, so do I keep all the conditionals inside the function?

Comment: You should probably start by learning basic Python syntax, see e.g. https://sopython.com/wiki/What_tutorial_should_I_read%3F

Comment: You should fix the formatting of the python code so that indentation is preserved, otherwise it's unreadable (especially since indentation matters, it changes the behavior of the code, in python!). You can use Ctrl+K around a block of code to indent it so that it becomes code, see https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to learn what return actually does. When the interpreter reaches a return statement in your code, it returns that value to wherever it was called from. For example, say I have a function `sum_two_vals`. This function takes two values for input `a` and `b` and returns their sum.

```
sum_two_vals(a, b):
    return a + b

print(sum_two_vals(4, 5))
```

This code is going to go the function `sum_two_vals`, execute whatever is in that function and then print out the result. When you return it sends whatever you are returning, back to where you called it from. Also you should note that when you return, all the subsequent code will not execute. When you return 'op' in like the third line of code (which by the way, op is completely undefined) none of the code following that return statement will execute. The problem you are given asks you to write code that takes one parameter, `operator`, and determine if its division or multiplication. You won't be asking for the user to input the `operator` value inside the function since this it is being passed in as a parameter.

Here is something closer to what your code should look like:

```
def multiply(operator):

    x = float(input('Enter number 1: '))

    y = float(input('Enter number 2: '))

    if operator == "*":

        return x * y

    elif operator == "/":
        return x / y

    else:
        return "invalid operator"

print(multiply(input("Enter '/' or '*': ")))
```

Read up on functions and how returns work [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_functions.htm). Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks a lot guys ! it's clear now and i'll read up on those links you gave me ASAP